# Replace values in NumPy array using indices given by another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm imagining something like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
rows = np.asarray([1,2,3])
cols = np.argmax(a[rows], axis=1)
indices = np.stack((rows, cols)).T
a[indices] = 1
```

The desired output for `a` would then be

```
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  1]
 [ 6  7  1]
 [ 9 10  1]]
```

However, this doesn't work and doesn't change `a`. How does it work?

Comment: And what is `b`?

Comment: Oops sorry, I forgot to rename it, too.

Comment: `a[rows,cols] = 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Change the penultimate line:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
rows = np.asarray([1,2,3])
cols = np.argmax(a[rows], axis=1)
a[rows, cols] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multidimensional "[fancy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays)":

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
rows = np.asarray([1,2,3])
cols = np.argmax(a[rows], axis=1)
indices = np.stack((rows, cols)).T
a[rows, cols] = 1
```